# In Azure App Services, do we need to clean out files in the LogFiles directory or does Azure have a cleanup process for this?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have started writing custom log files to Home\LogFiles in our Azure App Service.

Since Azure is not creating these logs, there are no settings in the Portal to control the retention policy.

Does Azure have a default process for cleaning up these files? Or will we need to manage that?

Are there any best practices for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is Azure will not cleaning up these files. Azure will not know about the logs, and will do nothing with them.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915520/custom-logs-in-azure-website-file-system-combined-into-single-log-file) is a similar issue, you could refer to it. This is the [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps), you could post your idea to improve Azure Web App.